# Exception thrown in catch and finally clause

Tags: java, exception

On a question for Java at the university, there was this snippet of code:

```
class MyExc1 extends Exception {}
class MyExc2 extends Exception {}
class MyExc3 extends MyExc2 {}

public class C1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.print(1);
            q();
        }
        catch (Exception i) {
            throw new MyExc2();
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print(2);
            throw new MyExc1();
        }
    }

    static void q() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw new MyExc1();
        }
        catch (Exception y) {
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print(3);
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}
```

I was asked to give its output.  I answered `13Exception in thread main MyExc2`, but the correct answer is `132Exception in thread main MyExc1`. Why is it that? I just can't understand where does `MyExc2` go.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

Based on reading your answer and seeing how you likely came up with it, I believe you think an "exception-in-progress" has "precedence".  Keep in mind:

**When an new exception is thrown in a *catch block or finally block* that will propagate out of that block, then the current exception will be aborted (and forgotten) as the new exception is propagated outward.  The new exception starts unwinding up the stack just like any other exception, aborting out of the current block (the catch or finally block) and subject to any applicable catch or finally blocks along the way.**

Note that *applicable catch or finally blocks* includes:

**When a new exception is thrown in a catch block, the new exception is still subject to that catch's finally block, if any.**

Now retrace the execution remembering that, whenever you hit `throw`, you should abort tracing the current exception and start tracing the new exception.

Comment: «Based on reading your answer and seeing how you likely came up with it, I believe you think an "exception-in-progress" has "precedence"» Thank you...that was exactly my thought :)

Answer (score 64):

**Exceptions in the finally block supersede exceptions in the catch block.**

[Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

> If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally
> block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
> - If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
> - If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

Comment: Instead of discarding reason R, would reason R be added to reason S as a suppressed exception?

Comment: @Nathan That's what I would have expected, but the language spec actually says the JVM should NOT add either as a suppressed exception, and explicitly says that `R` is discarded :/

Comment: Aha, `try-with-resources` says "An exception from the closing of one resource does not prevent the closing of other resources. Such an exception is suppressed if an exception was thrown previously by an initializer, the try block, or the closing of a resource." which is very different than `finally` blocks :/ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3

Answer (score 42):

This is what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling) says about finally clause:

> More common is a related clause
>   (finally, or ensure) that is executed
>   whether an exception occurred or not,
>   typically to release resources
>   acquired within the body of the
>   exception-handling block.

Let's dissect your program.

```
try {
    System.out.print(1);
    q();
}
```

So, `1` will be output into the screen, then `q()` is called. In `q()`, an exception is thrown. The exception is then caught by `Exception y` but it does nothing. A **finally** clause is then executed (it has to), so, `3` will be printed to screen. Because (in method `q()` there's an exception thrown in the *finally* clause, also `q()` method passes the exception to the parent stack (by the `throws Exception` in the method declaration) `new Exception()` will be thrown and caught by `catch ( Exception i )`, `MyExc2` exception will be thrown (for now add it to the exception stack), but a *finally* in the `main` block will be executed first.

So in,

```
catch ( Exception i ) {
    throw( new MyExc2() );
} 
finally {
    System.out.print(2);
    throw( new MyExc1() );
}
```

A **finally** clause is called...(remember, we've just caught `Exception i` and thrown `MyExc2`) in essence, `2` is printed on screen...and after the `2` is printed on screen, a `MyExc1` exception is thrown. `MyExc1` is handled by the `public static void main(...)` method.

Output:

> "132Exception in thread main MyExc1"

Lecturer is correct! :-)

*In essence*, if you have a **finally** in a try/catch clause, a finally will be executed (**after** catching the exception **before** throwing the caught exception out)

Comment: The `catch` is executed since `q()` threw an `Exception` from its own `finally` block.

Comment: "In q(), an exception is thrown but before the exception is fully thrown, a finally clause is first executed, so, 3 will be printed to screen. " Er... no, the first exception thrown in `q` passes execution to the empty `catch` block in `q` (which swallows this exception), then to the `finally` block in `q`.  Said finally block prints `3`, then throws a new exception, which thanks to `q`'s `throws Exception` is passed up the stack to the parent.

Answer (score 25):

Finally clause is executed even when exception is thrown from anywhere in try/catch block.

Because it's the last to be executed in the `main` and it throws an exception, that's the exception that the callers see.

Hence the importance of making sure that the `finally` clause does not throw anything, because it can swallow exceptions from the `try` block.

Comment: It will also be executed EVEN if there is no exception thrown in try/catch block

Answer (score 10):

A `method` can't `throw` two exceptions at the same time. It will always throw the last thrown `exception`, which in this case it will be always the one from the `finally` block.

When the first exception from method `q()` is thrown, it will catch'ed and then swallowed by the finally block thrown exception.

q() **->** thrown `new Exception` **->** `main` `catch Exception` **->** `throw` `new Exception` **->** `finally` throw a new `exception` (and the one from the `catch` is "lost")

Answer (score 5):

The logic is clear till finish printing out `13`. Then the exception thrown in `q()` is caught by `catch (Exception i)` in `main()` and a `new MyEx2()` is ready to be thrown. However, before throwing the exception, the `finally` block have to be executed first. Then the output becomes `132` and `finally` asks to thrown another exception `new MyEx1()`.

As a method cannot throw more than one `Exception`, it will always throw the latest `Exception`. In other words, if both `catch` and `finally` blocks try to throw `Exception`, then the `Exception` in catch is ***swallowed*** and only the exception in `finally` will be thrown.

Thus, in this program, Exception `MyEx2` is swallowed and `MyEx1` is thrown. This Exception is thrown out of `main()` and no longer caught, thus JVM stops and the final output is `132Exception in thread main MyExc1`.

In essence, if you have a `finally` in a `try/catch` clause, a `finally` will be executed **AFTER catching the exception**, but **BEFORE throwing any caught exception**, *and ONLY the lastest exception would be thrown in the end*.

Answer (score 4):

```
class MyExc1 extends Exception {}
class MyExc2 extends Exception {}
class MyExc3 extends MyExc2 {}

public class C1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.print("TryA L1\n");
            q();
            System.out.print("TryB L1\n");
        }
        catch (Exception i) {
            System.out.print("Catch L1\n");                
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print("Finally L1\n");
            throw new MyExc1();
        }
    }

    static void q() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.print("TryA L2\n");
            q2();
            System.out.print("TryB L2\n");
        }
        catch (Exception y) {
            System.out.print("Catch L2\n");
            throw new MyExc2();  
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print("Finally L2\n");
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }

    static void q2() throws Exception {
        throw new MyExc1();
    }
}
```

Order:

```
TryA L1
TryA L2
Catch L2
Finally L2
Catch L1
Finally L1        
Exception in thread "main" MyExc1 at C1.main(C1.java:30)
```

https://www.compilejava.net/

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to think of this is imagine that there is a variable global to the entire application that is holding the current exception.

```
Exception currentException = null;
```

As each exception is thrown, "currentException" is set to that exception. When the application ends, if currentException is != null, then the runtime reports the error.

Also, the finally blocks always run before the method exits. You could then requite the code snippet to:

```
public class C1 {

    public static void main(String [] argv) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.print(1);
            q();

        }
        catch ( Exception i ) {
            // <-- currentException = Exception, as thrown by q()'s finally block
            throw( new MyExc2() ); // <-- currentException = MyExc2
        }
        finally {
             // <-- currentException = MyExc2, thrown from main()'s catch block
            System.out.print(2);
            throw( new MyExc1() ); // <-- currentException = MyExc1
        }

    }  // <-- At application exit, currentException = MyExc1, from main()'s finally block. Java now dumps that to the console.

    static void q() throws Exception {
        try {
            throw( new MyExc1() ); // <-- currentException = MyExc1
        }
        catch( Exception y ) {
           // <-- currentException = null, because the exception is caught and not rethrown
        }
        finally {
            System.out.print(3);
            throw( new Exception() ); // <-- currentException = Exception
        }
    }
}
```

The order in which the application executes is:

```
main()
{
  try
    q()
    {
      try
      catch
      finally
    }
  catch
  finally
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that the finally block is executed after the the try and catch and is always executed....
But as you saw it's a little bit tricky sometimes check out those code snippet below and you will that
the return and throw statements don't always do what they should do in the order that we expect theme to.

Cheers.

```
/////////////Return dont always return///////

try{

    return "In Try";

}

finally{

    return "In Finally";

}

////////////////////////////////////////////


////////////////////////////////////////////    
while(true) { 

    try {

        return "In try";

   } 

   finally{

        break;     

    }          
}              
return "Out of try";      
///////////////////////////////////////////


///////////////////////////////////////////////////

while (true) {     

    try {            

        return "In try";    

     } 
     finally {   

         continue;  

     }                         
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////

/////////////////Throw dont always throw/////////

try {

    throw new RuntimeException();

} 
finally {

    return "Ouuuups no throw!";

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to walk the `finally` blocks:

1. Print "1".
2. `finally` in `q` print "3".
3. `finally` in `main` print "2".

Answer (score -1):

I think this solve the problem :

```
boolean allOk = false;
try{
  q();
  allOk = true;
} finally {
  try {
     is.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     if(allOk) {
       throw new SomeException(e);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you going to "solve"? Do you mean the question in the exam? well it already answered. If you mean the problem of the given code, since it is just a exam question there is no sense to blame it out.

Answer (score -1):

To handle this kind of situation i.e. handling the exception raised by finally block. You can surround the finally block by try block: Look at the below example in python:

```
try:
   fh = open("testfile", "w")
   try:
      fh.write("This is my test file for exception handling!!")
   finally:
      print "Going to close the file"
      fh.close()
except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
```