# Junit assert something after awaiting and handling an exception

Tags: java, junit, exception, mockito, assert

method which throws at first and second call:

```
public void foo() throws Exception
```

test:

```
@test
public void testFooThrowsAtFirstAndSecondTime(){
    boolean thrown;
    try {
       foo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       thrown = true;
    }
    assertTrue(thrown);

    thrown = false;
    try {
       foo();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       thrown = true;
    }
    assertTrue(thrown);

    foo();
}
```

Could you help me find a better solution for this?
Use of Mockito for a better solution would be also acceptable.

With better i mean, if i could avoid try/catch or even multiple try/catch in my test. In other languages or in jAssert i think even in spring there are statements like:

```
assertThrows(method(..)) //PseudoCode
```

I thought with Mockito or JUnit 4.x there is a similar thing.

I know about

```
@Test(expected=Exception)
```

But this would only be acceptable if i expect one throw and the test ends after that.

Comment: What is the problem?  What is the question?  You need a solution for exactly WHAT?

Comment: In jAssert or in other languages there are some things like assertThrow, which i would find besides being much more readable also somehow a more correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is that [*the try block is crucial*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13224598/1426891) if you want to resume execution after an exception. You can factor it out into a method or library, but it has to be called within your test method.

**Things that work:**

- The tried-and-true `fail()` idiom that [you and nrainier cite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28303290/1426891), which I prefer:

  ```
  try {
    foo();
    fail("foo did not throw an exception");
  } catch (Exception ex) { }
  ```
- [catch-exception](https://github.com/Codearte/catch-exception) is a library that, like Mockito, wraps the passed object and puts a try block around each method. Mockito's caveats about final methods and classes apply here too, so this won't always work.

  ```
  List myList = new ArrayList();
  catchException(myList).get(1);  // myList is wrapped here
  assert caughtException() instanceof IndexOutOfBoundsException;
  ```

  Note that catch-exception is in "maintenance mode" because the Java 8 solution (below) is much more solid.
- Any solution like `assertThrows(() -> methodThatThrows())` (Java 8) or:

  ```
  assertThrows(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() { methodThatThrows(); }
  });
  ```

  ...in Java 6/7. Importantly, *assertThrows is called before methodThatThrows*, so it can invoke methodThatThrows. Thanks Stefan for [pointing out Fishbowl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28306663/1426891), but you could easily write an equivalent yourself:

  ```
  public void assertThrows(Runnable block) {
    try {
      block.run();
      fail("Block didn't throw.");
    } catch (Exception ex) { }
  }
  ```

**Things that don't work:**

- `@Test(expected=YourException.class)` will go up the stack to the `try` block that JUnit wraps your test method in. Control never returns to the test method after that.
- JUnit4's `ExpectedException` @Rule looks tempting, but because it wraps the entire test method, you have to set expectations before calling the method that throws the exception.
- Anything that looks like `assertThrows(methodCallThatThrows())`. Java will try to get the return value out of `methodCallThatThrows` before `assertThrows` is ever invoked, so any `try` block there *can't help*.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think a one-liner per method invocation is possible.

I would write the test like this:

```
@Test
public void testFooThrowsAtFirstAndSecondTime() throws Exception {
  try {
    foo();
    fail("foo did not throw an exception");
  } catch (Exception ex) { }

  try{
    foo(); 
    fail("foo did not throw an exception");
  } catch (Exception ex) { }

  foo();
}
```

Comment: That would be also a valid solution but i was looking for something without the try/catch inside my test. Maybe i am going to refactor the try/catch routine in another function...

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you can use the [Fishbowl](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/fishbowl) library.

```
@Test
public void testFooThrowsAtFirstAndSecondTime(){
  Throwable firstException = exceptionThrownBy(() -> foo());
  assertEquals(Exception.class, firstException.getClass());

  Throwable secondException = exceptionThrownBy(() -> foo());
  assertEquals(Exception.class, secondException.getClass());

  foo()
}
```

It is possible to use this library with Java 6 and 7, too. But then you have to use anonymous classes.

```
@Test
public void testFooThrowsAtFirstAndSecondTime(){
  Throwable firstException = exceptionThrownBy(new Statement() {
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
      foo();
    }
  });
  assertEquals(Exception.class, firstException.getClass());

  Throwable secondException = exceptionThrownBy(new Statement() {
    public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
      foo();
    }
  });
  assertEquals(Exception.class, secondException.getClass());

  foo()
}
```

Comment: I currently use Junit 4 and Mockito (PowerMock), i discovered that in Spring or in jAssert there are assertThrow(..) statements. But i would rather stay on my current config if it's possible. We also are working on Java 7 btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unlucky enough to have to code for some version of java prior to 8, then you cannot do it with one line per exception.

But if you are using java 8, then you can do it as Stefan Birkner suggested.

Now, if you are unwilling to include an entire library for just one method, then here is a method that will work for you, copied [from my blog](http://blog.michael.gr/2014/09/assertions-and-testing.html)

```
public final <T extends Throwable> T expectException( Class<T> exceptionClass, Runnable runnable )
{
    try
    {
        runnable.run();
    }
    catch( Throwable throwable )
    {
        if( throwable instanceof AssertionError && throwable.getCause() != null )
            throwable = throwable.getCause();
        assert exceptionClass.isInstance( throwable ) : throwable; //exception of the wrong kind was thrown.
        assert throwable.getClass() == exceptionClass : throwable; //exception thrown was a subclass, but not the exact class, expected.
        @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
        T result = (T)throwable;
        return result;
    }
    assert false; //expected exception was not thrown.
    return null; //to keep the compiler happy.
}
```

So, your test code becomes something like this:

```
@Test
public void testFooThrowsAtFirstAndSecondTime()
{
    expectException( Exception.class, this::foo );
    expectException( Exception.class, this::foo );
    foo();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`@Test(expected=Exception.class)`

Comment: So, does your `foo()` method throw exceptions on first and second call and passes without exceptions on third one? I have no idea what does `foo()` do, but if you really need it, your test code solves your problem. Mockito solution will be slightly harder. Also consider redesigning your `foo()` method.

Comment: So, does your foo() method throw exceptions on first and second call and passes without exceptions on third one? Yes