# Unable to throw Exception, why?

Tags: java, exception

Within the first catch block why we can't throw an `Exception` object? Here `RuntimeException` is working fine.

```
public class CirEx {
    public Circle getCircle(int id) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("");

            Circle circle = new Circle(1, "");
            return circle;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
            // why we cann't do that.
            // throw new Exception(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the title to describe your actual problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779285/exception-thrown-in-catch-and-finally-clause

Comment: This is a badly formed question (because of the title), and there isn't really a problem with this code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can throw `Exception`, provided we declare the method to throw the same `Exception` (`throws Exception` clause) or handle it (using `try catch` block) .

`Exception` is a **checked exception** and these have to be handled

but

`RuntimeException` works because its **unchecked Exception** and for this we need not have a `throws` clause or handle it

[See Checked vs Unchecked Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation)

Comment: You don't need to declare runtime exceptions.

Comment: Have i mentioned that in the post? why downvote?

Comment: I just want to know the reason for my concept that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score -2):

Because in that case you will have to declare your method that it throws Exception.

```
 public Circle getCircle(int id) throws Exception{
Connection conn = null;
try {
    Class.forName("");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("");

    Circle circle = new Circle(1, "");
    return circle;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
    // why we cann't do that.
    // throw new Exception(e);
}

finally {
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Note:RuntimeException and its subclass are special type exception which don't need to be catched explicitely

Comment: How is it irrelevant?

Comment: You don't have to declare runtime exceptions.

Comment: That's what I have said and showed in example that it is perfectly okay to throw RuntimeException and but have to declare it if he wish to throw an Exception.