# Which Exception to be thrown?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Confusing{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Confusing cf = new Confusing();
        try{
            cf.confuse();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void confuse() throws Exception{
        try{
            throw new Exception("First Exception");
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new Exception("Second Exception");

            }finally{
            throw new Exception("Third Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

Why the result is `Caught exception: Third Exception`?

First in try, it throws the `First Exception` that is subsequently caught. Then throw the `Second Exception` and also in finally `Third Exception`. Why only the `Third Exception` is sent back to the main?

Comment: Java? Please make sure you tag what language.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779285/exception-thrown-in-catch-and-finally-clause

Answer (score 4):

It's right there in the Java language specification. (§11.3, *Run-Time Handling of an Exception*)

> If a try or catch block in a try-finally or try-catch-finally statement completes
>   abruptly, then the finally clause is executed during propagation of the exception, even
>   if no matching catch clause is ultimately found.
>
> If a finally clause is executed because of abrupt completion of a try block and the
>   finally clause itself completes abruptly, then the reason for the abrupt completion of the
>   try block is discarded and the new reason for abrupt completion is propagated from there.