# What will happen if catch block or finally block having some exception?

Tags: java, exception

In exception handling, what will happen if catch block or finally block having Exception?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3779677/1743852

Comment: That exception gets thrown.

Comment: Why not try it? Experimentation is the best teacher.

Answer (score 5):

Finally block exception will mask the original exception.

When an new exception is thrown in a catch block or finally block that will propagate out of that block, then the current exception will be aborted (and forgotten) as the new exception is propagates outward.

Check [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/finally-explained-common-questions-uses.html) and [here](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/11/playing-with-try-catch-finally-in-java.html) for more details

Comment: mask will be better than override.

Comment: @JunedAhsan : Yep, corrected.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/durgaeducation
, Here you can find all cases in exception handling

Answer (score 1):

As per the JLS 14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally

> If the catch block completes abruptly for reason R, then the finally block is executed. Then there is a choice:
>
> > If the finally block completes normally, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason R.
> >
> > If the finally block completes abruptly for reason S, then the try statement completes abruptly for reason S (and reason R is discarded).

A finally block may throw an exception and if so, any exception thrown by the try or catch block is lost.

Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2