# Exception Handling flow discrepancy

Tags: java, exception

My code is below :-

```
class Varr {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        try {
            System.out.println(10/0);
        }
        catch(ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("catch1");
            System.out.println("catch1");
            throw new ArithmeticException ("Exce");             
        }
        finally {   
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output is :-**

> ```
> catch1
>
> catch1
>
> finally
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: Exce
>   at one.Varr.main(Varr.java:22)
> ```

As per my knowledge the flow has to be first try then catch and finally at last but as per the output the flow is try then few lines of catch upto the throw exception statement and then finally and the throw exception statement of catch block at last.

**Why is there discrepancy in flow, I mean why finally was executed before the throw new exception statement of catch block**

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3779677/7459622

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because a block of `finally`, by definition, has to be executed no matter the outcome of the `try` or `catch` clauses.

In your case, the run-time knows there is an exception that has to be propagated upwards, but before doing so, it executes whatever is inside the `finally` block.

When the `finally` block is finished, it propagates any exception that might have been raised, or the flow continues otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a clarification please :-

In case at run time if throw new exception statement of catch block is executed before the finally block then the exception object will get handover to the JVM and the programs terminates abnormally without finally getting chance, right ?

and also if there is an exception in finally block itself then exception will be thrown of finally block without executing the throw exception statement of catch block, right ?

Comment: What do you need to have clarified?

Comment: The order is like this: try-catch(es)-finally. After finally, if there's any exception on-hold, it will be thrown, otherwise it continues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a clarification please :- In case at run time if throw new exception statement of catch block is executed before the finally block then the exception object will get handover to the JVM and the programs terminates abnormally without finally getting chance, right ? and also if there is an exception in finally block itself then exception will be thrown of finally block without executing the throw exception statement of catch block, right ?

Comment: Take it as a buffered throw. Like if there is a finally block, any un-caught or re-raised exception before the start of the finally block is put into the buffer, and when it finishes, it is propagated upwards if the buffer is not empty. As you said if there's any exception in the finally block it is immediately thrown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [essentials of finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This
>   ensures that the `finally` block is executed even if an unexpected
>   exception occurs.

Comment: if this is the case then why first   "System.out.println("catch1");
            System.out.println("catch1");" statements of catch block gets executed before the finally block ?

Comment: @bharatbhushan *This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs.*...so once the unexpected exception occurs the finally is executed and then the exception is thrown. Point to note is until your second  `System.out.println("catch1");` there is nothing like an unexpected exception.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a clarification please :- In case at run time if throw new exception statement of catch block is executed before the finally block then the exception object will get handover to the JVM and the programs terminates abnormally without finally getting chance, right ? and also if there is an exception in finally block itself then exception will be thrown of finally block without executing the throw exception statement of catch block, right ?

Comment: *programs terminates abnormally* =>  from the same doc -- *If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.*