# How to display exceptions both from catch and finally?

Tags: java, groovy

let's consider the following code:

```
try {
    throw new Exception("from try")
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new Exception("from catch")
} finally {
    throw new Exception("from finally")
}
```

It gives:

```
Exception thrown
java.lang.Exception: from finally
<...>
```

So it looks that *finally* is executed before *catch* and terminates execution flow.

What could I do if want to see both exceptions?

Comment: You can't throw *two* times in a method. If you throw on the `finally` cause, the throw statement from the catch() block won't execute. On the other hand, (obviously) if you use System.out.println(..), you will see all messages

Comment: Not sure on your actual problem though. If you perform some cleanup in the `catch` block and the cleanup code can throw, you could use nested: `.. catch { try {..} catch{..}}`

Comment: In `Java` `Finally` block is always Executed you cannot throw exception two times in a method. Try block are handled in`catch` exception.

Comment: The problem is with exceptions from the underlying library. I have a resource creation in *try* block and cleanup in *finally* block. 

Cleanup fails with an exception when a resource was not created, and the exception for resource creation is hidden by the exception in *finally*, so I can not find what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> So it looks that finally is executed before catch and terminates
>   execution flow.

That is not correct.  `finally` is executed after a correspondeing `catch`, not before.  The issue is that your `catch` block executes, and then after that the `finally` block is guaranteed to execute.

Comment: I think in addition to this, you can get at the exception thrown from the catch block in the suppressed exceptions of the exception thrown from the finally block.

Comment: @emilles - I don't think there would be any suppressed exceptions in the scenario described in the original question.  Am I mistaken about that?

Comment: I tried this in the debugger and no suppressed exceptions are available.  So no easy way to get to exception thrown from catch block.

Answer (score 0):

This post will help you I guess:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779285/exception-thrown-in-catch-and-finally-clause
```